# Override function in CS5 IDE -> Timeline -> Framescript

Tags: actionscript-3, function, overriding

I have a baseclasse which implements an interface. I use this baseclass as my "template" ( read: Semantics, i'm not talking about Java/C++ Templates).

In my Flash CS5 IDE I want to override these interface methods. 
Yes they are implemented in the base class, but trying to override them in framescript throws me( YES this might probably not be a clean design):

```
Symbol 'GameTest', Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 1 1024:
        Overriding a function that is not marked for override.
```

I don't exactly know in what scope framescripts work. And by framscript I just mean in the timeline frame 1.

in my base class:

```
public class MiniGameTemplate extends MovieClip implements IMiniGame
{ 
   public function MiniGameTemplate()
   {

   }


   public function update():void 
   {

   }
}
```

In my Library object's first frame:

```
 override function update():void
{

}
```

I'm using actionscript linkage to inherit my library object from the base class.
If I clear the framescript, it runs fine. No error.

Comment: @Florent Thats all the code I have. There is nothing more to it beside the " extends and implements".

Comment: Where is the _base class_ definition? Please paste the entire class definition!

Comment: @Florent The Base class runs fine. It goes wrong in the IDE the moment I try to override it. Updated my post. Adding more code is redundant. This is it a nutshell.

Comment: Would like to know why it got downvoted.

Comment: It bugs me when people down vote and have nothing to say. Sorry, I can't help on this one

Comment: @Ronnie It's cool, thanks for understanding. It irks me as well.

Comment: So you have a movie clip with the base class of `MiniGameTemplate` is that right?

Comment: @Ronnie Yes my library object is set with the baseclass MiniGameTemplate

Comment: Why are you putting code inside the movie clip to begin with? You should just set a linkage name on the clip and then create an instance of it inside `MiniGameTemplate.as`

Comment: @Ronnie I don't want the library object inside my baseclass. I'm going to create several library objects that actually represent the minigames. It's meant so I can interface these objects in my main game loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When overriding a method, you must structure the overriding method ***exactly*** like the original. In this case you've missed the `public` access modifier statement.

Solution:

```
override public function update():void {

}
```

Comment: Modifiers are not allowed in frames. This is the whole problem. I removed the public modifier from the base but even then it's just throwing errors.

Comment: Not a problem, just create a subclass of `MiniGameTemplate` where you move all logic from the frame and then let the library object inherit from this class. This basically does the same thing but will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: The idea was to create the minigame in the flash IDE with instance name and such. If I would move the code to seperate files it would just be more of a hassle to make all of the minigames.

Comment: You will still be able to access instance names. If you are using the approach above where the library object is inheriting from your subclass, you need to define the instance names in the class. Another solution that may be simpler in your case is to set the library object to inherit directly from the `MiniGameTemplate` and let your subclass inherit from your library object. Then you can basically just copy/paste the timeline code into the subclass.

Comment: I am aware of that. I rather want to approach it the way im trying to make it work now. But it sounds like you can't override methods in the frame?